# Arranging the content of a grid in a reduced space with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-grid

More exactly, I'd like the date and category to always be at the bottom, but no lower than the thumbnail, regardless of the height of the title. When the title is too long, the "surplus" should not be visible.

When on mobile devices, some of my posts look as this:

[image: this is what I have]

some as this:

[image: this is what I have]

What I want to achieve is this:

[image: this is what I want]

```css
article {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-column-gap: 0.5rem;
  grid-template-areas: "A B";
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
}

img.thumbnail {
  min-width: 144px;
}

.entry-header * {
  line-height: 18px;
}

.entry-title {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.entry-meta {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<article class="post">
  <div class="post-thumbnail">
    <a class="post-link" href="example.com/post_title">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.jpg" class="thumbnail">
    </a>
  </div>

  <header class="entry-header">
    <h2 class="entry-title">
      <a class="post-link" href="#">Post Title</a>
    </h2>

    <div class="entry-meta">
      <span class="posted-on">2023.05.05</span> |
      <span class="posted-in">Category</span>
    </div>
  </header>
</article>
```

Comment: as a side note, it is not recommended to hide a text (or part of) for accessibility reasons. this is more a design issue.

Answer (score 2):

Convert the container `.entry-header` to a flexbox container with `display: flex;`. Then you can push the `.entry-meta` element to the bottom of the container by adding `margin-top: auto`

```css
article {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-column-gap: 0.5rem;
  grid-template-areas: "A B";
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
}

img.thumbnail {
  min-width: 144px;
}

.entry-header * {
  line-height: 18px;
}

.entry-title {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.entry-meta {
  font-size: 12px;
}

/* added CSS */
.entry-header {
  display: flex
}

.entry-meta {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<article class="post">
  <div class="post-thumbnail">
    <a class="post-link" href="example.com/post_title">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.jpg" class="thumbnail">
    </a>
  </div>

  <header class="entry-header">
    <h2 class="entry-title">
      <a class="post-link" href="#">Post Title</a>
    </h2>

    <div class="entry-meta">
      <span class="posted-on">2023.05.05</span> |
      <span class="posted-in">Category</span>
    </div>
  </header>
</article>
```

Comment: After adding the `flex-flow: wrap;` to `.entry-header` your solution works well, even if it doesn't hide the extra text. I agree with the accessibility reasons mentioned by @fabrizio-calderan, but in this particular case they will be applied only partially.

Answer (score 0):

The following javascript will get the height of the image and entrymeta, then the height of the title to image height minus entrymeta height so that the title will never be longer than the image height. I think it is a better solution. Hope it helps.

```js
  window.onload = function() {
  var thumbnail = document.querySelector('.thumbnail');
  var imgHeight = thumbnail.offsetHeight;
  var entryMeta = document.querySelector('.entry-meta');
  var textHeight = entryMeta.offsetHeight;
  var entryTitle = document.querySelector('.entry-title');
  var titleHeight = imgHeight - textHeight*2;
  entryTitle.style.height = titleHeight + "px";
  };
```

```css
article {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-column-gap: 0.5rem;
  grid-template-areas: "A B";
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
}

img.thumbnail {
  min-width: 144px;
}

.entry-header * {
  line-height: 18px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.entry-title {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.entry-meta {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: auto; /* push to bottom of .entry-header */
}

/* added CSS */
.entry-header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /* stack title and class .entry-meta vertically */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<body>
<article class="post">
  <div class="post-thumbnail">
    <a class="post-link" href="example.com/post_title">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.jpg" class="thumbnail">
    </a>
  </div>

  <header class="entry-header">
    <h2 class="entry-title">
      <a class="post-link" href="#">Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title Post Title</a>
    </h2>

    <div class="entry-meta">
      <span class="posted-on">2023.05.05</span> |
      <span class="posted-in">Category</span>
    </div>
  </header>
</article>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You move the element out of the flow and will cause a collision of the elements and text when the title is larger than the image as in the picture on mobile view.

Comment: @tacoshy You are right, so I edited my answer, is that a viable option?